# Ubuntu Lamp php script with mySQL connection not using Apache

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, cron, lamp

Hi I got a strange problem with my LAMP installation

I'm using an Ubuntu Server with PHP5 Apache and mySQL, all runs great when accessing via http.

But the thing is, I also want to trigger some scripts using bash, basically so I can trigger them at will and prevent them being used via Apache/HTTP

The scripts themselves run when called with php5, all includes are found. 
But for some unknown reason mySQL does not seem to initiate the Database the way it does via Apache. I just get a message back saying no database is connected.

Is there some special setup for bash related php calls?

Comment: Should be a problem with your includes. Show some code pls. If you want to test, try connecting to mysql inline, not using an included file, see if that works

Comment: I checked that, all Includes are being read. I can even echo the the mySQL settings. 

It works on commercial servers, but I also want it to work on the server I set up myself. I clearly must have something to do with linux php setup. But I'm a dev, not a sysadmin, so there must be something missing in my settings

Ubuntu 12.04, standard LAMP setup
I'm using vhosts in apache
mod_rewrite & curl enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There are no special DB settings for PHP run from Bash, However because I work on several Servers I was using the **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** variable to determin which login credentials should be used. Therefore it only worked on the server where the default credentials were correct.

For now I just put in an extra option in the code that uses credentials based on the value of the **dirname(__FILE__)** variable. Works great.